# Split R string into individual characters

Tags: r, strsplit

I think this should be simple, but I can't find another example that works for my purposes. I have many DNA sequences in 1 column in R, but I would like to split them into many columns with 1 base pair per column. For example:

```
V$1
ggggcc
cccctt
tttttt
aaaaaa
```

I want it to look like

```
V$1 V$2 V$3 V$4 V$5 V$6
 g   g   g   g   c   c
 c   c   c   c   t   t
 t   t   t   t   t   t
 a   a   a   a   a   a
```

I have tried

```
paste(L1HS2, collapse = "")
unlist(strsplit(L1HS2, split = ""))
```

and

```
data.frame(str_split_fixed(L1HS2, "", max(nchar(L1HS2))))
```

But I lose the data frame structure and end up with 1 very long row with many columns. This has to be easy, right?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could use

```r
data.frame(Reduce(rbind, strsplit(df$V1, "")))
```

This returns

```r
     X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
init  g  g  g  g  c  c
X     c  c  c  c  t  t
X.1   t  t  t  t  t  t
X.2   a  a  a  a  a  a
```

or

```r
data.frame(do.call(rbind, strsplit(df$V1, "")))
```

which returns

```r
  X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
1  g  g  g  g  c  c
2  c  c  c  c  t  t
3  t  t  t  t  t  t
4  a  a  a  a  a  a
```

Answer (score 2):

Another possible solution:

```r
library(tidyverse)

df <- data.frame(V1 = c("ggggcc", "cccctt", "tttttt", "aaaaaa"))

str_split(df$V1, "", simplify = T) %>% data.frame

#>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
#> 1  g  g  g  g  c  c
#> 2  c  c  c  c  t  t
#> 3  t  t  t  t  t  t
#> 4  a  a  a  a  a  a
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `separate` from `tidyr`.

```
# first the data:
'V1
ggggcc
cccctt
tttttt
aaaaaa' %>% data.table::fread(data.table = FALSE) -> df

sl <- seq_len(nchar(df$V1[1]))
separate(df, V1, paste0('X', sl), sep = sl)
```

> ```
>   X1 X2 X3 X4 X5 X6
> 1  g  g  g  g  c  c
> 2  c  c  c  c  t  t
> 3  t  t  t  t  t  t
> 4  a  a  a  a  a  a
> ```

Separating on the empty string (`""`) doesn't work very nicely with `separate`, so I `separate` on each numeric position instead.

Comment: That use of `sep` is quite interesting. Didn't know `sep` accepts _indexing vectors_. Great!

Comment: Me neither, but I checked the help file to look at the weird empty string separation, and there it was.